# Generalized computer code to find combinations without repetition

Tags: fortran, combinations

I have to find all the combinations without repetition (nCr) for a given array.
For example if the array = positions = (/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5/), and I want to find combinations of 3 (here, r =3), all the combinations are,
           (1           2           3;
           1           2           4;
           1           2           5;
           1           3           4;
           1           3           5;
           1           4           5;
           2           3           4;
           2           3           5;
           2           4           5;
           3           4           5)

My problem is to generalize this procedure for any value of r. According
to my current code, the number of for loops increases with increasing r.
Is it possible to generalize this process for any r with fortran?

My current code for r=3

```
program combinations

integer i,j,k,l
integer loc1,loc2,loc3
integer, dimension(5) ::positions

positions = (/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5/)

do i =1,5
 loc1 = positions(i)
  do j =1,5
   if (j .gt. i) then
    loc2 = positions(j)
     do k=1,5
      if (k .gt. j) then
       loc3 = positions(k)

       write(*,*) loc1,loc2,loc3

    endif
   enddo
  endif
 enddo
enddo

end program
```

`

Comment: Apart from the tag, is anything else python here?

Comment: Python [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function documentation contains generic python algo.

Comment: Python tag removed??? You want it only in fortran?

Answer (score 0):

In case of python, "there is a built-in method for whatever" ;-)

```
from itertools import combinations
list(combinations(range(1, 6), 3))
# Output will be [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5)]
```

Have fun :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is Heap's algorithm:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm

The pseudocode in the article can easily be translated into Fortran. Do not forget to declare the subroutine as `RECURSIVE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  COMMON ICOUNT
  CHARACTER *70 OFIL
  OFIL='ALLCOMB.TXT'
  WRITE(*,*)'FEED N AND M (NOTE: N OR M LARGER THAN 20 TAKES TIME)'
  READ(*,*) N,M
  WRITE(*,*)'FEED FILE NAME TO STORE RESULTS'
  READ(*,*) OFIL
  ICOUNT=0
  CALL COMBIN(N,M,OFIL)
  WRITE(*,*)'OVER'
  END
  !---------------------------------------------------------------
  SUBROUTINE COMBIN(N,M,OFIL)
  PARAMETER (MX=20)! MX IS MAXIMUM DIMENSION
  ! Program by SK Mishra http://skmishra.net/computer-programs/comb.txt
  COMMON ICOUNT
  INTEGER A(MX),B(MX),C
  DOUBLE PRECISION NCM,IC
  CHARACTER *70 OFIL
  OPEN(15,FILE=OFIL)
  NCM=1
    DO I=1,M
    A(I)=I ! A IS LEAST INDEXED COMBINATION
    B(I)=N-M+I ! B IS MAXIMUM INDEXED COMBINATION
    NCM=NCM*B(I)/I ! TOTAL POSSIBLE COMBINATIONS
    ENDDO
  IF(M.GT.0) THEN
  ICOUNT=ICOUNT+1
  WRITE (15,*) (A(I),I=1,M), ICOUNT! INITIAL (LEAST INDEXED) COMBINATION
  ELSE
  WRITE(15,*) 'NONE'
  ENDIF
  INCMPL=1
  IC=1
  ! --------------------------------------------------------------
  DO WHILE (INCMPL.NE.0 .AND.INT(IC).LT.NCM)
  INCM=0
    DO I=1,M
    INCM=INCM+(B(I)-A(I))
    ENDDO
  INCMPL=INCM
  A(M)=A(M)+1
    DO I=1,M
    II=M-I+1
      IF(A(II).GT.B(II)) THEN
      A(II-1)=A(II-1)+1
         DO J=II,M
         A(J)=A(J-1)+1
         ENDDO
      ENDIF
    ENDDO
  IC=IC+1
  ICOUNT=ICOUNT+1
  WRITE(15,*)(A(K),K=1,M),ICOUNT
  ENDDO ! END DO WHILE LOOP
  ! --------------------------------------------------------------
  CLOSE(15)
  RETURN
  END
```

Comment: What does this  code do? It is recommended to post me than just some code dummp but also some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The key idea is to transform a decimal number into binary by using the intrinsic function btest. Integer with kind=4 overflow when n>=32. The following code has a better efficiency if r close to n/2.

```
program combination
implicit none
integer(4),parameter :: n=5, r=3
integer(4),dimension(r) :: loc
integer(4) :: i,kr,i10,nCr
nCr=0
decimaloop:do i10=0,2**n-1
  kr=0
  do i=1,n
    if(btest(i10,i-1)) then
      kr=kr+1
      if(kr<=r) then
        loc(kr)=i
      else
        cycle decimaloop
      endif
    endif
  enddo
  if(kr==r) then
    nCr=nCr+1
    print 100,nCr,loc(:)
  endif
enddo decimaloop
print'("nCr=",i)',nCr
100 format(i10,3x,32i3)
end program combination
```